# PHP form doesnt output expected string

Tags: php, forms

I'm sorry for this stupid question but I'm just starting out with coding. I'm following tutorial on youtube and my code isn't doing what the mentor is showing.

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        echo 'form is submited';
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <title>PHP OOP Tutorial</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="new-user">
        <h2>Create new user</h2>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST"></form>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your form is closed `</form>` __incorrectly__

Comment: You need to tell us what the expected result is, and what the current result is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your form is empty:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST"></form>
```

Since your inputs and submit button are outside the form, they don't do anything.  Wrap them in the form:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
    <label>Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This will allow the submit button to submit the form in which it's placed.  The result should then be that upon submitting the form your string is output.  (Though keep in mind that you're outputting that string *before the HTML document*.  It may or may not be visible in the browser, but should be visible in the page source.)

Comment: Ty David, I missed it completly